# Can't iterate through range if there is another element on the loop to iterate. Why is that?

Tags: python, for-loop, iterator, range

Here is my code. I'm doing a puzzle and need the index of the second zipped element, but since `goals2.index(j)` only returns the first occurrence, I tried to use a range which iterates at the same time:

```py
def best_match(goals1, goals2):
    a = [goals1[0] - goals2[0], 0, goals2[0]]
    for (i, j), k in zip(goals1, goals2), range(len(goals2)):
        if i - j < a[0]:
            a[0] = i - j
            a[1] = k
            a[2] = j
        if i - j == a[0] and j > a[2]:
            a[1] = k
            a[2] = j
    return a[1]
```

However, when the interpreter reaches the `for` part of the code, it gives me an error saying that ***int object is not iterable***, when range clearly IS an `iterable`. It only doesn't work when I iterate multiple values using range as one of the iterators.

Comment: You need to add range to the `zip` currently you are trying to iterate over a tuple' that contains a zip object and a range object

Comment: Also, you should probably just use `enumerate`